# fopen($filename, "a+") nor file_put_contents($filename, = $data.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND) seem to append to file

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, file-put-contents

Trying to append file with either:

```
file_put_contents($filename, "\r\n" . $barcode_number.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

or

```
$myfile = fopen($filename, 'a+');
```

neither appending my file. Both are over writing old information 
Things I have tried are in code comments

```
    $myfile = fopen($filename, 'a+') or die("unable to open file" . $filename);

    $barcode_number = $_POST['SBN'];
    //$newLine = PHP_EOL; 
    //echo  $temp.$barcode_number; die();

    fwrite($myfile, $barcode_number.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($myfile, "\n");

    //file_put_contents($filename, "\r\n" . $barcode_number.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    fclose($myfile);
    //echo "wrote " . $barcode_number . "to " . $filename; die();
```

Expected output is:

```
123456
123457
123458
```

actual output is:

```
123458
```

Comment: Look like no issue in code. Your you define '$filename'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `file_put_contents()` call is formatted correctly, although I don't think you need the .PHP_EOL, since you're already prepending the data with "\r\n". So is your `fopen()`/`fwrite()`/`fclose()`. Is it possible that another script is opening this file, and thus locking the file?

Comment: This was exactly it. I was initially opening the file with write and didn't close it. So there was some over writing issues